# How to disable header but use enhancedlist on visualforce page? or alternative?

Tags: apex, visualforce, home-page-component

I built a visualforce page that basically points to a case view and added it to the Salesforce home page. Only problem is the enhancedlist can't be used in conjunction with showheader="false". I don't want the header or sidebar to show in the visualforce component. Is there a way I can do this and not have the header show up? Or is there an alternative? Thanks!

`<apex:page sidebar="false">
 <apex:enhancedlist type="Case" height="730" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="25"                 Listid="00TQ00000045QP3" />
 </apex:page>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out : http://www.ca-peterson.com/2011/11/magic-isdtp-param.html

The isdtp param strips the header off but there is a word of caution using this. I combined this with Iframe and was able to strip the header and sidebar off

As per the blog : 
vw - used by the service cloud console. This is the only option that supports the new aloha theme. It strips the salesforce header and sidebar from the page. There's some small functionality degradation (enhanced lists are not longer enhanced, some ugly styles here and there) but this is your only option if you want to include chatter support through isdtp.

I had to therefore try with Iframe instead of enhanced list

https://na14.salesforce.com/500?fcf=00Bd0000003jFUo&isdtp=lt  is nothing but I clicked on the case and went to the view and took the URL related to the view.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showheader="false" controller="case_ext"> 
<apex:iframe src="https://na14.salesforce.com/500fcf=00Bd0000003jFUo&isdtp=vw"/>
</apex:page>
```

thanks to you I learnt something new :D I felt that the most fantastic part is that you do not have to worry about mentioning saveURL and retURL explicitly since the view will return back to the same apex page after save and cancel :)

Comment: I tried it. It works! It's basically exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: great that it helped. But do look at the word of caution and remember that it could be breaking off anytime and if it does dont panic \m/

Answer (score 2):

when we inject in this way  , header will not appear. But inline editing feature goes away. inline editing depends on JS which is inturn injected using header.
so better option will be

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
   <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQuery_New)}"/>
   <apex:enhancedlist type="Case" height="730" customizable="false" rowsPerPage="25" Listid="00TQ00000045QP3" />
   <script>
        $('.bPageHeader').hide();
        $('.globalHeaderBar').hide();
   </script>
</apex:page>
```

we are trying to hide header using jquery.